# .htaccess - Redirect All URLs + Existing Directories to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to be able to redirect absolutely all URLs in a directory to the index.php file in the directory. Unlike for all of the other answers I've found, this *includes existing directories and existing files.* I am using Apache with an .htaccess file to accomplish this. So far my .htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /sub/directory/index\.php - [L]
RewriteRule - /sub/directory/index\.php
</IfModule>
```

But for some reason it doesn't redirect anything to index.php. I've also tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /sub/directory/index\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /sub/directory/index\.php
</IfModule>
```

But this gives me an inevitable "500 Error". What am I doing wrong? How can I simply redirect everything to index.php?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with this [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule /sub/directory/index\.php - [L]
```

See [What is matched?](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched)

> - In *per-directory context (Directory and .htaccess)*, the Pattern is matched against only a partial path, for example a request of "**/app1/index.html**" may result in comparison against "**app1/index.html**" or "index.html" depending on where the RewriteRule is defined.

and "Per-directory Rewrites":

> - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, **a Pattern with ^/ never matches** in per-directory context.

This means, the leading slash prevents the pattern from matching. Changing it to

```
RewriteRule ^sub/directory/index\.php - [L]
```

will fix the problem.

---

The [500 Internal server error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) comes from the second rule (in combination with the non-matching first rule).

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /sub/directory/index\.php
```

This will rewrite any request to `/sub/directory/index.php`, which in turn will be rewritten again to `/sub/directory/index.php`, and so on until the rewrite module gives up and shows a "too many redirects" error or similar.

Comment: You were right. That line wasn't matching, causing the issue! Thanks!
Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question, but the .htaccess file is actually *in* the '/sub/directory/' folder. Thus, once I stripped it down to just,
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Still have no idea why my second original .htaccess file didn't work, but the following finally got it working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/sub/directory/index.php
RewriteRule .* /sub/directory/index.php
</IfModule>
```

However, I'll happily accept any answer that can well explain why my second original file kept giving me a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors, additionally re-matching the first rule after the second match (not last).

any-request -> /sub/directory/index.php -> /sub/directory/index.php - [L]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteRule /sub/directory/index\.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/directory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My other suggestion (index.php is the directory index file and is the first in order when requesting the directory):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^sub/directory/(.*)$ /sub/directory/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can use this code: (comment second and third line to accept even files and directory in url)

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I can fix it somehow (not in a smart way I guess).
The problem is because HTML does not change to the root folder.

I can solve mine by use HTML "base tag" (you can the path to adapt with the root directory you want.

You also need to give a condition to allow this change only on the targeted page.